# Can I install windows 7 x64 in a VPC where the host is vista x86?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, 64-bit, microsoft-virtual-pc, 32-bit

Before I waste my time trying is this possible?

If not, i'll just install win 7 x86 on the VPC.

Comment: Anybody actually succeeded in doing this? I have a x64 supporting hardware and still VirtualBox errors, saying 64bit not supported by host.

Comment: To answer your second question: You need to check in the BIOS of your machine if the Virtualization Extensions are enabled, if your motherboard supports it. Disclaimer: I wrote a article on this topic available here: http://diago.co.za/articles/64bit-virtual-machine-guest-requirements.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can install a 64bit guest OS on a 32bit host if your hardware is x64 compatible, and your virtualization software supports it. At least [VirtualBox](http://virtualbox.org) does, but I believe Virtual PC does not.

Comment: Dammit +1 For beating me by a minute.

Comment: The current release of Virtual PC (version 2007) actually doesn't support x64 guest OS's at all. I think the new Windows Virtual PC for Windows 7 will; I hope.

Comment: @Chris The 64Bit Virtual PC for Windows on 7 does have limited 64Bit support. There is a push for it to happen however it will be a while after release.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox does support this in certain scenorios but generally no.

[Factor Mystic](https://superuser.com/questions/24965/can-i-install-windows-7-x64-in-a-vpc-where-the-host-is-vista-x32/24969#24969) posted the details before I got a change to edit.

Answer (score 1):

Some hypervisors (VirtualBox and some versions of VMware--maybe also others) do support 64-bit guests on 32-bit hosts, as long as your CPU is 64-bit, supports Intel VT or AMD-V, and has VT or AMD-V enabled: https://serverfault.com/questions/52442/can-an-x86-host-run-x64-guests

Answer (score 0):

Like the first answer described it. Yes, you can. Just make sure you enable 64bit on the CMOS settings, this option is only available if the processor is 64 bit compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Depends if your processor supports enumeration of x64.

I'd go with a fresh install if you have access to the RTM build. You'll see a jump in performance over a VPC installation.