# Virtual machine running 64bit from a 32bit system

Tags: 64-bit, virtual-machine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install windows 7 x64 in a VPC where the host is vista x86?](https://superuser.com/questions/24965/can-i-install-windows-7-x64-in-a-vpc-where-the-host-is-vista-x86)

Is it possible to install a 64bit OS on a virtual machine program which is running on a 32bit OS? and if it is then how?

I've tried VirtualBox and VMWare, both reported and error saying they cannot run 64bit.
Is there a setting to adjust, a different version of the VM to use or is it simply not possible?

My hardware is 64bit compatible:
- CPU: Core 2 Duo T5750
- MotherBoard: MSI MS-1636

Comment: The duplicate refers to Windows 7 however it applies to any 64Bit OS on 32Bit. VirtualBox supports it if Intel Extensions is enabled.

Comment: What is "Intel Extensions"? it is not mentioned in the "duplicate". using virtualBox, I'm still encountering the same error.

Comment: While the "duplicate" discusses the same issue, it does not deal at all with solving the error I'm getting, it only says "yes it is possible". Nothing on the how is mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, I can't find such an option in the BIOS, so I'll assume it doesn't support it. :(
  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know (certainly the case with VMWare), a virtual machine can only be 64 bit if the host system is running a 64 bit OS also.

I expect a 64 bit virtual machine runs as a 64 bit process within the host, thereby enforcing that requirement.

Comment: Duplicate article suggests it is possible

Comment: Yes, for VirtualBox. Not VMWare or Virtual PC. So I was both right and wrong :)

Comment: Newer versions of VMware reportedly also work.  http://serverfault.com/questions/52442/can-an-x86-host-run-x64-guests