# Can a 64-bit OS run as a guest on a 64-bit VirtualBox host?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

Is it possible to run a 64-bit OS as a guest on a 64-bit machine with VirtualBox? I'm guessing it should be, but I'd like to make sure.

Do some virtualization technologies allow a single guest machine to use multiple cores? I guess it should be possible, but my VirtualBox open-source edition doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: You can even run 64-bit guests on 32-bit hosts (although when I tried it I just got blue screens).

Comment: Related Question: http://superuser.com/questions/24965/can-i-install-windows-7-x64-in-a-vpc-where-the-host-is-vista-x86. It explains what is needed to run x64 Guest on x64 Machines. Theoretically this is a duplicate of the mentioned question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can run a 64-bit OS as a guest with VirtualBox on a 64-bit host.

VirtualBox will definitely allow usage of multiple cores on guest machines, but it depends on your hardware - quintessentially your CPU.

For example, on certain Intel CPUs - especially the Duo Core (Celeron) series, it does not support VT-x technology, and also does not support EMT64 technology, thus you are limited to running only on a single core, and 32-bit guest OSes.

Check your processor, the defining factors are there.

[Intel Processor Spec Finder](http://processorfinder.intel.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Although, you need your BIOS to support virtualisation extensions

Comment: Someone else did too. Really makes you want to answer, doesn't it?