# How can I see if my computer can host a 64bit virtual machine?

Tags: 64-bit, virtual-machine

I'd like to learn how to use Microsoft Forefront. I need a 64Bit machine to do so. How can I check if my computer can host a 64bit virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

Use [securable](http://www.grc.com/securable.htm). The bit length and Hardware Virtualization governs if you can run a 64-bit OS in a virtual machine

[image]

Comment: Also, related: [Install VM running 64-bit OS on 32-bit machine](http://superuser.com/questions/24965/can-i-install-windows-7-x64-in-a-vpc-where-the-host-is-vista-x86)

Comment: My physical machine is a 64bit machine :)

Comment: @Sergio Okay :-) Just wanted to cover all bases :)