# Is it possible to run 64bit guest system on 32bit host system under VMware Workstation?

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation, ubuntu-server

I saw this question aleady [Can I install windows 7 x64 in a VPC where the host is vista x86?](https://superuser.com/questions/24965/can-i-install-windows-7-x64-in-a-vpc-where-the-host-is-vista-x86), but I haven't seen any talk about `VMware Workstation`.

I have version 7 and it is currently installed on 64bit Windows7 also I have installed 64bit `Ubuntu Server` on Workstation.

Question is: can I copy and run this 64bit Ubuntu Server VM under same `VMware Workstation 7` on 32bit Windows7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, if your host's CPU is 64-bit and supports VT, then you should be able to do it.

[Rob's answer in the question you linked](https://superuser.com/questions/24965/can-i-install-windows-7-x64-in-a-vpc-where-the-host-is-vista-x86/38015#38015) pretty much nails it.

[This VMWare KB article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1003945) explains the host machine hardware and firmware requirements for installing virtual machines with 64-bit guest operating systems.

[Here is a tool from VMWare](http://downloads.vmware.com/d/details/processor_check_5_5_dt/dCpiQGhkYmRAZQ==) to test for 64-bit capabilities in your CPU.

I have not personally tried it with VMWare Workstation (used VirtualBox to do it), but there seems to be plenty of anecdotal evidence it works based on the answers in this StackOverflow question: [Can I run a 64-bit VMWare image on a 32-bit machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56124/can-i-run-a-64-bit-vmware-image-on-a-32-bit-machine)

Comment: I think, that should help. I have AMD Turion 64 x2 TL-52, so I guess it should be compatible.